# OnMouseOver() alternative for iPhone (Unity3D/Unity2D)

Tags: unity, iphone, touch

I am currently developing a game that uses the OnMouseOver() function of a MonoBehaviour object.

Is there a true alternative for iPhone? Would I be better of coding my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no support in unity for your finger hovering over the screen... You will have to implement a touch system yourself. Input.touches is an array of current fingers on the screen. You might find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [TouchInputModule](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-TouchInputModule.html) on iOS and other mobile devices.

You just need a collider on the object you want to touch or hover, [EventSystem](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) AND [TouchInputModule](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-TouchInputModule.html) in the scene, and then it basically works this way:

```
public class TouchInputExample : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.log("Touched");
    }
    public void OnPointerEnter(EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.log("Hover start");
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.log("Hover stop");
    }
}
```

As mentioned, you can not get a hover status on a touch screen. It always either touches or not.